# How to get linq extension methods parameter info and summary?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

```
var linqMethods = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
                 .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

In this above code, I'm using to getting the linq methods. Same way how to get linq methods parameter info and summary?

I'm getting Linq Methods using `c#`
[image]

I Expect this Parameter info using `c#`
[image]
I Expect this method summary Info using `c#`
[image]

Comment: Why are you accessing Linq methods with reflection? What is the end goal? And what do you mean by `summery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parameters of the methods by call *GetParameters()* on the single MethodInfo object.

The summary information is stored in an separate XML file located in the same directory as the System.Linq.dll.

I suppose you want to build a kind of documentation. So maybe you can get all necessary information by parsing this XML file.

Comment: Where located the System.Linq.dll xml file?

Comment: E.g. in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore`. There are subdirectories for installed .NET versions.